# How to find the process id of the process that issued a system call in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I have added a custom system call in Linux Kernel. Now I want to find out the id of the process which issued that system call.
If I use **current** pointer in the system call, I will get the information of the currently running process. It may not be the actual process which issued the system call especially in a multi-process environment.
For example, in a user space program I have the code.

```
int pid = fork();
if(pid < 0) {
    <statements>;
} else if(pid == 0) {
    mysystemcall();
}
```

This is just an illustration. Now we don't know the order of execution of the parent and child process. Inside a system call, the **current** pointer may not be pointing to the task_struct of the parent process which issued that system call.
So how can I find that process

Comment: `current` is always the process that issued the system call. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434651/what-is-the-current-in-linux-kernel-source).

Answer (score 1):

current always points the task_struct for the process which invokes your custom syscall, therefore read and return the `current->tgid`, as this returns the pid of the process which invokes the system call. Note the `pid` is the process id and `tgid` is the thread group id, so for heavy weight process, as invoked by `fork()`, pid == tgid.